# Problems writing script for blackjack game

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script for a Black Jack game but have run into some problems. This is the code I've included in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var J = 10;
var Q = 10;
var K = 10;
var A = 11;
var deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A];

function deal() {
var test = "hello";
var f_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
var s_card = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
var card1 = deck[f_card];
var card2 = deck[s_card];

if (card1 == J) {
    card1 = "Jack";
    }
else if (card1 == Q) {
    card1 = "Queen";
    }
else if (card1 == K) {
    card1 = "King"
    }
else if (card1 == A) {
    card1 = "Ace"
    }

if (card2 == J) {
    card2 = "Jack";
    }
else if (card2 == Q) {
    card2 = "Queen";
    }
else if (card2 == K) {
    card2 = "King"
    }
else if (card2 == A) {
    card2 = "Ace"
    }

var bucket = card1 + ", " + card2;
var res = f_card + s_card
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = bucket;
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = f_card + ", " + s_card;
if (res == 22) {
    alert("Blackjack!")
    }
}
</script>
```

The body reads as follows:

```
<body>
<form>
    <input type="button" value ="Deal" onclick="deal()" /><br /><br />
</form>
<div id = "result">
</div><br />
<div id = "test">
</div>
</body>
```

I added the "test" div to see what was happening inside the deal, and it looks like "Jack" is being assigned to all array value above 9. How can I have the other if statements processed as well? Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but your problem is that `J == Q == K == 10`, they're all equal to each other so any card that's equal to a K (ideally, a king) is also equal to a J. And you test for J first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your J,Q,K,A in quotes:

```
var deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A'];

if (card1 == 'J') {
    card1 = "Jack";
    }
```

etc..

Comment: Or perhaps more suitable for this problem: `var deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A'];`

`if (card1 == 'J') {
    card1 = 10;
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (card1 == J) {
    card1 = "Jack";
    }
else if (card1 == Q) {
    card1 = "Queen";
    }
else if (card1 == K) {
    card1 = "King"
    }
```

Lets say you have a card == 10 (Jack / Queen / King)

You test with `if`s.

the first `if` is hit because 10 == J

Even if it is a Queen / King (which also == 10)

Because the Jack is hit in the if statement the other ifs dont get run

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `card1` and `card2` in `if else` ladder use "original card ID", ie

```
switch (f_card){
  case 10: card1 = "Jack";
           break;
  case 11: card1 = "Queen";
           break;
  case 12: card1 = "King";
           break;
  case 13: card1 = "Ace";
           break;
}
```

Comment: Scratch that. Under this solution Kings > Queens and Queens > Jacks etc. That shouldnt be happening...

Comment: @user858962 Huh? This must be some other problem as here is just code to select "cards name". Youre missing `if(f_card > 9) card1_value = 10;` somewhere or some such...